# Update Craft 2 to 3?

Tags: craft3

Now Craft 3 is available as a download, do you need to use composer for any part of upgrading a Craft 2 site to Craft 3 (if Craft 3 has been downloaded)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Detailed instructions are now provided here: https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/upgrade.html

Comment: Thanks, just reread - nice touch that composer isn't required for those not ready for it just yet, even though it appears the more efficient approach

Answer (score 1):

I found this video more helpful. But yes, you'll need composer is you are going to follow this video

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i029_DNFsmc&ab_channel=CraftQuest